# Thunderbird - Restoring old messages to an IMAP account

Tags: thunderbird

I had an email account that I had used in thunderbird for a couple of years now. I had been backing up the emails (msf files) for a while as well. I just moved my domain to a new hosting site and can no longer access my previous emails. I have the messages stored on my local machine via Inbox.sbd and its corresponding msf files. My questions is, is there anyway for me to restore those messages considering that I am using IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a POP account and just copied and pasted all the files there. Once they showed up in the POP thunderbird account, I just moved them to the IMAP account.